# C: Using getopt_long for flags only, no switches. Program only sees first flag

Tags: c

I apologize this is been asked before. I looked around but couldn't find a post relevant to this specific situation

Right now, I'm implementing two flags, --save and --load. Eventually, they'll handle saving and loading dungeon files for a roguealike, but right now I just want them to do something at all. Here is the relevant portion of my code, from main.

```
static struct option long_options[] = {
  {"load", no_argument, &load_flag, 1},
  {"save", no_argument, &save_flag, 1},
  {0,0,0,0},
};
while((c = getopt_long(argc, argv, "f", long_options, NULL)) != -1) {
    break;
}
if(load_flag == 1) {
     printf("hey, the load flag works \n");
}
if(save_flag == 1) {
     printf("And the save flag works as well! \n");
}
```

From what I understand, the conditional from the while statement should actually set the flags. However, the [code i adapted it from](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=175771&seqNum=3) also included an option that had a required element, so it has a switch statement and an optstring argument. I tried to modify the code to fit my situation, but something got lost in translation. I also had to leave the optstring argument in getopt_long, even though it does nothing in my code.

When I run my modified code, either --save OR --load works, but if I use both, it only registers the first one entered. Unfortunately, my specs say both can be used at once, so here we are.

My questions are as follows.

1. Why does only the first flag get assigned, and what do I have to do to fix it?
2. Does it have something to do with leaving the optstring argument "f" in getopt_long to satisfy the compiler? Is that the wrong approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `break` stops the `while` loop after the first iteration, so it only checks the first option. I'm guessing that you originally had a `switch` statement there, so the `break` was used to exit the `switch` and continue with the `while` loop. Since you don't have `switch`, an empty `while` loop should work instead.

Other issues:

- You shouldn't pass in `"f"` if you don't want a `-f` option to be accepted.
- You may also want to check for a `'?'` return value, which indicates when an unknown option was used.